# How can you get the subtasks using the Asana REST API?

Tags: asana

Last week Asana anounced the new sub tasks capability (http://blog.asana.com/2012/10/introducing-asana-subtasks/). Does anyone know how to access subtasks using the REST api? They are not documented at http://developer.asana.com/documentation

When I emailed Asana api-support, they said to ask the question here! ...not sure what that is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tasks API to get a list of the subtasks, e.g.

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/2139407382883/subtasks

and then use the subtask IDs you get back with the tasks API.  That is, a subtask is treated as a bono fide task by the API.